# terminal process completed

Tags: terminal, zsh

whats wrong? why this happened?
i can't use terminal and write anything after 'process completed'.

```
Last login: Thu Jul 27 02:17:19 on ttys000
export MAVEN_HOME=$HOME/apache-maven-3.9.3
export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
cat .zshrc
export MAVEN_HOME=$HOME/apache-maven-3.9.3
export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
exit

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Are you using zsh or bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using zsh. To fix,

- Open `~/.zshrc` in TextEdit
- Remove the last line (the one with `exit`)
- Save file and quit TextEdit

Now start Terminal again.

Comment: thank you so so much <3